# MMF/non-MMF share pricing and interest rate

Tags: pricing, mutual-fund

For equities and bonds there are specific models to determine the intrinsic value of stocks/bonds, respectively, mainly following the idea that the stocks/bonds are worth the sum of all of its future cash-flows, discounted back to their present value. Thus, both of them to some extent are also connected to the interest rate environment.

For stocks, e.g., the dividend discount model:

$P=\dfrac{D_1}{r-g}$,
with $P=$ current stock price, $D_1=$ the value of dividends at the end of the first period, $g=$ growth rate of dividends, and $r=$ cost of equity.

For bonds, e.g.,

$V=\sum\dfrac{C}{(1+r)^t}+\dfrac{F}{(1+r)^T}$,
with $V=$ value of the bond, $C=$ coupon payments, $r=$ discount rate, $F=$ face value of the bond, $t=$ number of periods, and $T=$ time to maturity.

Is there a similar simple concept for MMF/non-MMF shares that also relates the pricing to the interest rate? Frequently, I find references that the price of a mutual fund share is referred to as the net asset value per share, but this doesn't really help.

Comment: You are right that MF's or ETF's are generally valued by adding up the market values of the constituent securities, i.e the NAV method. Not by forecasting future cash flows. In a sense they are considered a "derivative" composed of known elements, not a "primitive" security requiring a theory to explain their valuation.

Comment: @nbbo2 That was my fear. Are you aware of any other means in this context to establish this relationship to interest rates?